# iOS background location tracking after reboot

Tags: ios, location, core-location

Imagine i am setting up a location background task, for my iOS app, to track the users location. The user granted my app access to his location "**Always**". Does this mean, the background tasks runs only when started from the app, until the phone ist shut down, or does this mean, that the location background task is restarted after rebooting the os?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you have access to location services even when the app isn't in the foreground. However, you must have some active task such as navigation in process.

The **Always** API function isn't tantamount to constant background execution.

Comment: It means a app who is tracking my movements all the time is not possible with ios?

Comment: According to this, your answer might be wrong: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services  

"Your app can use all location services, and it can start those services from either the foreground or the background. If a location-related event occurs when your app is not running, the system launches your app and delivers the event."

But this not answers the question, if the background task is restarted after a reboot.

Comment: @NiklasRaab yes, but you cannot execute arbitrary code.

Answer (score 0):

A task has to belong to a process. If the thread's process does not work, the thread can not work. So, the answer is the first, the background task runs only when started from the app. Because your background task belongs to your app that means your process.

You have to create a system thread if you want it to work even if your process kills. But, most operating systems do not allow the user to do if you do not develop a device driver.

Comment: iOS don't i think so

Comment: If you develop a device driver, you may. Otherwise no.

Comment: According to this, your answer might be wrong: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services "Your app can use all location services, and it can start those services from either the foreground or the background. If a location-related event occurs when your app is not running, the system launches your app and delivers the event." But this not answers the question, if the background task is restarted after a reboot.

Comment: No, it says that If a location-related event occurs when your app is not running, the system launches your app. it does not mean that event is your background thread. When your app starts, your background thread can start.